# Disable creation and use of API credentials

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to spin up a new pod that doesn't automatically include a JWT for talking to the k8s cluster.

I've created a new Service Account and tried removing the built in secret, but it is automatically regenerated after each delete.

According to the [secrets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/#service-accounts-automatically-create-and-attach-secrets-with-api-credentials) documentation, I should be able to disable the creation of tokens for service accounts.

> The automatic creation and use of API credentials can be disabled or overridden if desired.

Where/how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing the `--service-account-private-key-file` argument from the controller manager will prevent auto-creation of tokens

removing the ServiceAccount admission plugin will prevent auto-mounting of tokens

however, many services are likely to depend on those tokens being present.

if you are concerned about access to the API, it is generally better to set an authorization mode other than AlwaysAllow, and use one of the modes that lets you specify policy around which users can perform which actions

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. Do you know if either of these options is possible on GKE?